# Download sharepoint reports in excel format programatically

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, export-to-excel

I have sharepoint 2010 server with a report (WorldPopulation.rdl) on it.

This report is connected to a SQL server.

I want to create a webservice which can return this report in excel format  or in some other format which can further be converted to excel.

Answer (score 0):

[EXPORTING A SQL SERVER REPORTING SERVICES 2005 REPORT DIRECTLY TO PDF OR EXCEL](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/10/29/exporting-a-sql-server-reporting-services-2005-report-directly-to-pdf-or-excel.aspx) maybe help